# How can I create a separate module for role based permissions in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

#### Feature Description:

3 different roles to be created in the system to manage access.

[image]
[image]

#### Use Case Description:

Administrator: To have full access

Handler: One who can just add and issue inventory. Cant check stock or have access to any report.

Manager: One who can access stock and other reports

#### Detailed Description:

Create roll management tab to handle users tab

Accessibility.

Admin have ability to give access only particular tab
to particular user only.

Add Search functionality
Job List with navigation.
Create Job roles

Assign access to different modules for that job role

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create groups and add permissions to Group. And finally, add user to group. Below is just an example, Please explore it.

1.create group and add permission to group

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission, User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType 

# import User model 

new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name ='Administrator') 

# Code to add permission to group 
ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(YourTable) 

# If I want to add 'Can go Haridwar' permission to level0 ? 
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename ='can_add', 
                                    name ='Can add in your table', 
                                            content_type = ct) 
new_group.permissions.add(permission)
```

2.Add user to group

```
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
group = Group.objects.get(name='Administrator')
user.groups.add(group)
```

3.Based on the user group, you can control your system.

Comment: Refer it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/

Comment: how can I create permissions.
Like I have 3 apps in my project:-
1) app1
2) app2
3) users management(for add, update, read, delete users)
Now I want to create one more app name as 'Access'.
Here I want to create groups and add permissions for app1, app2 and users management